# do_action() Wordpress / PHP

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

**EDIT:** I JUST realized I never used the do_action() to call the functions - reading up on some documentation for do_action() right now but I am hoping that solves it!

I have some $wp_customize settings and controls for a specific page that aren't showing up when I go to edit the custom template.

**In my functions.php file:
**

```
add_action("wp", "checkPage");
function checkPage(){
    if(!is_admin()){
        wp_reset_query();

         if (is_page('find-your-trip')) {
            include(dirname(__DIR__).'/BOAT-wordpress-theme/pageFunctions/findYourTripFunctions.php');
            }
                     elseif (is_page('home')) {
                        include(dirname(__DIR__).'/BOAT-wordpress-theme/pageFunctions/homeFunctions.php');

                     }
                       elseif (is_page('who-we-are')) {
                        include(dirname(__DIR__).'/BOAT-wordpress-theme/pageFunctions/whoWeAreFunctions.php');
                                 }
                                 elseif (is_page('what-we-do')) {
                                    include(dirname(__DIR__).'/BOAT-wordpress-theme/pageFunctions/whatWeDoFunctions.php');
                              }
                              elseif (is_page('support-our-mission')) {
                                 include(dirname(__DIR__).'/BOAT-wordpress-theme/pageFunctions/supportOurMissionFunctions.php');
                           }
                              elseif  (is_page('annual-report')){
                                 include(dirname(__DIR__).'/BOAT-wordpress-theme/pageFunctions/annualReportFunctions.php');
                           }
                           // $boatCurrentPage = json_encode($currentPage);
                           // echo $boatCurrentPage;
                           // var_dump($boatCurrentPage);
                        }
                     }
                     checkPage();
```

**In my findYourTripFunctions.php file:
**

```
add_action('customize_register', 'boat_findyourtrippage_callout');

function boat_findyourtrippage_callout($wp_customize) {
   $wp_customize->add_section('boat-findyourtrippage-callout-section', array ('title' => 'Find your trip'));

   $wp_customize->add_setting('boat-findyourtrippage-callout-image');

   $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Cropped_Image_Control($wp_customize, 'boat-findyourtrippage-callout-image-control', array (
   'label' => 'Find your trip header image',
   'section' => 'boat-findyourtrippage-callout-section',
   'settings' => 'boat-findyourtrippage-callout-image',
   'height' => 590,
   'width' => 1920
   
   )));

   $wp_customize->add_setting('boat-findyourtrippage-callout-headline', array(
      'default' => 'Header'
      ));
      
      $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Control($wp_customize, 'boat-findyourtrippage-callout-headline-control', array (
      'section' => 'boat-findyourtrippage-callout-section',
      'settings' => 'boat-findyourtrippage-callout-headline'
      )));

      $wp_customize->add_setting('boat-findyourtrippage-callout-paragraph', array (
         'Enter paragraph here'
         ));
         
         $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Control($wp_customize, 'boat-findyourtrippage-callout-paragraph-control', array (
         'label' => 'Text',
         'section' => 'boat-findyourtrippage-callout-section',
         'settings' => 'boat-findyourtrippage-callout-paragraph',
         'type' => 'textarea',
         
         )));
      }

      add_action('customize_register', 'boat_findyourtripcenter_callout');
function boat_findyourtripcenter_callout($wp_customize) {
   $wp_customize->add_section('boat-findyourtripcenter-callout-section', array ('title' => 'General Trip Information'));

   $wp_customize->add_setting('boat-findyourtripcenter-callout-headline', array(
      'default' => 'General Trip Information'
      ));
      
      $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Control($wp_customize, 'boat-findyourtripcenter-callout-headline-control', array (
      'section' => 'boat-findyourtripcenter-callout-section',
      'settings' => 'boat-findyourtripcenter-callout-headline'
      )));

}
```

When I use the WP Console plugin and enter function boat_findyourtrippage_callout($wp_customize) it comes back as **null.
**

Does $wp_customize not count as a value being passed?

When I try to add the below to the bottom of the findyourtripfunctions page I get hit with an undefined error.

```
               function page($currentPage) {
                  global $currentPage;

                  if ($currentPage == "Find Your Trip") {
                     echo $currentPage;
                     boat_findyourtrippage_callout($currentPage);
      
                  }
               }
               $currentPage = "Find Your Trip";

               page($currentPage);
```

And if I try to pass $wp_customize straight to boat_findyourtrippage_callout I get hit with a " Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function add_section() on null
in C:\Users\Melis\Local Sites\boat\app\public\wp-content\themes\BOAT-wordpress-theme\pageFunctions\findYourTripFunctions.php on line 6."

Do I need to encode my code into JSON for wordpress?
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_json_encode/

I've read the documentation a few times and maybe I just need to take a walk around the block and come back with fresh eyes:
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/customize-api/

If anyone has any pointers or documents to reference on this I would really appreciate it. The customizer is driving me nuts and I'd really like to figure out how to get those options to load.